# How to write a hello world in spring scala

Tags: spring, scala, sbt

I started to learn scala and now I need to write a simple Hello world application on spring mvc framework. I tried to find a good reference on internet but I couldn't. Can somebody please help me. (I use fedora 17 and sbt as building tool)

Comment: Why do you want to implement it with spring . i guess Play and lift are the most usefull frameworks for scala

Comment: http://sobychacko.wordpress.com/2013/05/21/spring-integration-scala-dsl-samples-helloworld/

Comment: there are quite a lot of tutorials about Scala + Spring, for example:
http://parleys.com/play/51c1ad7ee4b0d38b54f4621e/chapter12/about

If you simply want to learn scala - play is better. Spring will give you large overhead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are learning both spring and scala, I think you should start with this: http://spring.io/blog/2013/08/06/spring-boot-simplifying-spring-for-everyone and try to develop it in Scala

this is a very good start for developing Spring apps ( even spring mvc apps ), I think with this you can combine spring and scala easily.

If you are serious about Scala and Web then you can try the mentioned Play!, Lift, Scaladin ( https://github.com/henrikerola/scaladin ) Scalatra frameworks.

If you want to use some nice Scala features in your Spring apps then maybe check this : http://spring.io/blog/2012/12/10/introducing-spring-scala

Answer (score 0):

I search google for you,hope it helps you

http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.8/reference/mvc.html

Answer (score 0):

Check out the following:
http://pivotallabs.com/spring-4-mvc-scala/
I think its is exactly what you are looking for.